# Django - Set initial selected value for formd.MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to display initial values as selected on a MultipleChoice form field in Django when the form loads. I populate a formset with different forms. Each form has only one field 'answer', which is initialized based on a custom parameter passed to the form's init() method.

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize label & field 
        :returns None:
        """
        question = kwargs.pop('question')  # A Question object
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if question.type == Types.RADIO:
            choices_ = [(op.id, op) for op in question.option_set.all()]
            self.fields['answer'] = forms.ChoiceField(label=question.statement,
                                                      initial=1,
                                                      widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                                      choices=choices_)
        elif question.type == Types.CHECKBOX:
            choices_ = [(op.id, op) for op in question.option_set.all()]
            self.fields['answer'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=question.statement,
                                                              initial=[1,3],
                                                              widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                                              choices=choices_)
```

This renders the following HTML:

[image: Checkbox rendered]

But it doesn't get into the form's cleaned_data. When I submit formset, the request.POST data goes into this view:

```
    def post(self, request, form_id):
        """
        Process & save the responses obtained from a form into DB
        :param request: An HTTPRequest object
        :param form_id: form id whose responses arrive
        :returns HttpResponse object with a results template
        """
        formset = FormHandler.AnswerFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                            form_kwargs={'questions': FormHandler.qs})

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                # Access cd['answer'] here but cd appears to be empty dict {}
                # with no key named 'answer'
```

The `cleaned_data` does have the correct 'answer' value in the case of Radio, but in this case, it doesn't contain the list of selected IDs which it should. I've checked that request.POST.getlist('form_#_answer') does show the correct list of ['1', '3'] but it somehow doesn't get into the formset's cleaned_data. I've spent hours trying to find out why this happens. Can't find the answer anywhere in the Django docs either. Can anyone explain why this is happening?